# ESP32 2 SPI connnection ethernet shield and usb host

Tags: ethernet, esp32, usb-host, nodemcu

Is it possible to have two SPI connection for ESP32

1. for ESP32 below link for the product

https://www.amazon.co.uk/AZDelivery-NodeMCU-CP2102-Development-Parent/dp/B07ZZFXRTY

2. for ethernet shield
   below link for the product

[https://www.amazon.com/HiLetgo-Ethernet-Network-Interface-WIZ820io/dp/B08KXM8TKJ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08KXM8TKJ)

3. for USB host
   below link for the product

https://www.banggood.com/id/Mini-USB-Host-Shield-2_0-ADK-SLR-Development-Tool-p-1175308.html

With below pinout :

```
Ethernet CS -> Esp32 pin =  5
USB CS -> Esp32 pin = 15
Ethernet and USB CLK -> Esp32 = 18
Ethernet and USB MISO -> Esp32 = 23
Ethernet and USB MOSI -> Esp32 = 19
```

below picture for Ethernet and USB shield

[image: https://www.amazon.com/HiLetgo-Ethernet-Network-Interface-WIZ820io/dp/B08KXM8TKJ]

[image: https://www.banggood.com/id/Mini-USB-Host-Shield-2_0-ADK-SLR-Development-Tool-p-1175308.html]

Regards,
Rizki

Comment: Pictures won't help. Which ESP32 module, which Ethernet module, and which USB module you are talking about? Add make, model, link to datasheet of all devices to your question.

Comment: done, already update the question

Comment: Those are links to seller sites. There are no manuals how to use these available from these sites. Besides the last link does not even work.